# Auto increment sequence in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to implement *Auto increment* in uisng mongoose.
But I am stuck.

*Counter Schema*

counter.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var counterSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    sequence_value: {type: Number, default: 1}
});

var Counter = module.exports = mongoose.model('Counter', counterSchema);
```

**Product Schema**

products.js

```
var productsSchema = new Schema({
    productId: {type: String, require: false},
    merchantId: {type: String, required: false}
)}
```

I have created counter collection and inserted one record inside it.

```
{
    "_id" : "productId",
    "sequence_value" : 1
}
```

Include method to increment the counter in the counter collection

```
//COUNTER COLLECTION
function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName){

   var sequenceDocument = Counters.findOneAndUpdate({
      query:{_id: sequenceName },
      update: {$inc:{sequence_value:1}},
      new:true
   });

   return sequenceDocument.sequence_value;
}
```

Calling method to increment sequence number:

```
product.productId = getNextSequenceValue("productid");
```

But it's not working, nothing is getting saved in the products collection?

Comment: can you post the code, how are you saving the document and calling the sequence?

Comment: Calling getNextSequence :: `product.productId = getNextSequenceValue("productid");``Products.create(product, function(err, product){
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }else{
      res.json(product);
    }
});`

Comment: you have defined you schema that `productId` as `String` but sequence is a `Number`

Comment: can you print the `product` as json to console before insert/create?

Comment: I have modified my schema

Comment: I tried printing sequence value, but it's coming as `undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163105/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-saravana).

Answer (score 0):

the next sequence should be

```
product.productId = getNextSequenceValue("productId"); // camelCase
```

in the counter collection you have added document with key `productId` (camelCase) but trying to get sequence with key `productid` (all lowercase)

**mongo CLI**

```
> function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName){
... 
...    var sequenceDocument = db.counters.findOneAndUpdate(
...       { "_id" : sequenceName },
...       { $inc : { sequence_value : 1 } },
...       { new : true }
...    );
...    return sequenceDocument.sequence_value;
... }
>
```

**EDIT-2** with mongoose

```
var counterSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: { type: String, required: true },
        sequence_value: { type: Number, default: 1 }
    }
);

var Counters = mongoose.model('Counters', counterSchema);

var productsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    productId: {type: String, require: true},
    merchantId: {type: String, required: false}
});

productsSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var doc = this;
    Counters.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: 'productId' },
        { $inc : { sequence_value : 1 } },
        { new : true },  
        function(err, seq){
            if(err) return next(err);
            doc.productId = seq.sequence_value;
            next();
        }
    );
 }
);

var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productsSchema);
var testProduct = new Product({merchantId : 'test'})

testProduct.save(function (err, doc){
    console.log('saved ' + doc )
})
```

output (with generated productId)

```
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$ node app.js
`open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
Mongoose: counters.findAndModify({ _id: 'productId' }, [], { '$inc': { sequence_value: 1 } }, { new: true, upsert: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
Mongoose: products.insert({ productId: '36', merchantId: 'test', _id: ObjectId("5a5b27b860716d24007df611"), __v: 0 })
saved { __v: 0,
  productId: '36',
  merchantId: 'test',
  _id: 5a5b27b860716d24007df611 }
^C
saravana@ubuntu:~/node-mongoose$
```

Comment: `function getNextSequenceValue(sequenceName){

   var sequenceDocument = Counters.findOneAndUpdate({
      query:{_id: sequenceName },
      update: {$inc:{sequence_value:1}},
      new:true
   });
  console.log('Counter value::' + sequenceDocument.sequence_value);
   return sequenceDocument.sequence_value;
}`

Comment: in above code `console.log` is printing `undefined`

Comment: have you tried `var sequenceDocument = Counters.findAndModify(...)` ?

Comment: yup, then I am getting `Counters.findAndModify` is not a method error

Comment: @mayankbisht see my edit in `findOneAndUpdate` method

Comment: Yup, con CLI it's also working for me. The problem is with server side. It's not working on the server side

Comment: @mayankbisht its due to the asyc behaviour of js, the method call does not wait till we get the id, for this we can plugin pre hooks in schema, so that when we call save this pre hook will be called automatically and set the generated id, please check the edit-2